# Configuring mongoDB IP address for CRUD application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a CRUD application, and I have a question regarding the IP address configuration.

I've allowed access from everywhere by setting access to `0.0.0.0/0`, since I'm going to have users from all over the place interacting with the database. Does this cause a security issue?

Before anyone gets mad at me, I've looked through the docs trying to find an answer and this is the closest information I've found https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/data-explorer and I'm also a beginner following a MDN tutorial but I wan't to make sure I configure everything the way it should be for a real project.

Comment: Aren't you afraid that someone will just delete all of your collections and databases?

Comment: Did you enable authentication?

Comment: @StephenTaylor I am, but I'm looking for solution to allow people to have access to create new models in my database through the website, without having access to delete all of the collections and databases

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I'm not sure what that is

Comment: you need to enable authentication first. Second create customized role then create a user and password which will be able to do only allowed operations. You can also whitelist  specific IPs only with **authenticationRestrictions** option.

https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/mongodb/mongodb-create-user-assign-roles/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to follow below steps:

- enable authentication first.
- create customized role
- create a user and password *which will be able to do only allowed
  operations.*

You can also whitelist specific IPs only with **authenticationRestrictions** option. Please find below links:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/
https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/mongodb/mongodb-create-user-assign-roles/

Comment: thanks for the reply. currently I'm signing users up with mongoose, and they cant sign in (have access) until they confirm their email. then they can simply fill out forms on the website to create objects in the database. will I run into any issues if I leave my access as `0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: if you want to connect your mongodb publicly then leave it as 0.0.0.0/0.